# save and load menu state c#

Tags: c#, toolstripmenu

I'm using a Windows form app in which I have a menu with 2 options. The user can check which option should run at start up and the app remembers it for the next time the user open the app.
I'm having difficulties in finding the correct parameter for the ToolStripMenu.
I save and load the state the user checked, and insert it to the Setting tab.
But what is the correct way to write it?
This doesn't work(for loading it from the settings):

`ToolStripMenuItem.CheckState =
            Properties.Settings.Default.menu_at_start;`
This does not work either :

```
labToolStripMenuItem.Checked =
        Properties.Settings.Default.menu_at_start;
```

I defined the 'menu_at_start' parameter as a System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem in the settings GUI.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should define 'menu_at_start'  as bool.

Comment: and then define the labToolStripMenuItem.... as?

Comment: Isn't it a ToolStripMenuItem on your form?

Answer (score 0):

> I defined the 'menu_at_start' parameter as a System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem in the settings GUI. Any ideas?

Define 'menu_at_start' as bool in settings.settings